# UIView animateWithDuration not working for iPhone X simulator and device

Tags: objective-c, uiview, autolayout

UIView animateWithDuration not working in iPhone X and simulator.
Its working fine for simulator when simulator zoom out but its get stuck when simulator Zoom In.

Note:- For all other devices its working great without any issue.

Here is my code:-

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:^{
    viewBoundry.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians(Boundedangele));
     [objClip updateAngle:Boundedangele];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using duration 0? Try using  [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

Comment: [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            imgRotation.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(imgRotation.transform, direction);
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        } completion:nil];

Yes, used [self.view layoutIfNeeded] this one also but same result, not working. 

See this case happen when I am continuously updating transform by using rotate gesture. But I am surprised that its working for all other devices and not for Iphone  X

Answer (score 0):

Review the constraints in your UIView that could be affected by the animation.

Your animations may be breaking constraints that are only relevant in the iPhone X layout and because of this the completion block never gets called.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for reply.

Yes, As you said I checked constraint, All are perfect.
for more satisfaction I removed constraint and checked again but same think happen, not working smoothly.